# Accessing variables in a SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, variable

Trying to build a string with the the parts of a SOQL query.  I cant get the syntax right with the `Account.name` and Count fields, even tried the alias `name` and 'co'.

```
`List < AggregateResult > AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                                    FROM Case
                                                    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND Id in :Trigger.New
                                                    GROUP BY Account.Name, AccountId
                                                    HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 8
                                                   ];`

message = 'Account name: ' + string.valueOf(AggregateResultList[0].name) +
                ' has ' + integer.valueOf(AggregateResultList[0].co)+
                ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
```

I am receiving errors:

`Variable does not exist: name`
`Variable does not exist: co`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `AggregateResult`, you need to use the `.get(String)` method to access things.

e.g. `AggregateResultList[0].get('name');`

The return value of the sobject's `.get()` method is an `Object`, which means you'll need to do a typecast to make the result usable. Something like `String name = (String)AggregateResultList[0].get('name');`